# How to Pass or Inject an Unknown Number of Objects in a Method Call

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

How do I pass, inject or instantiate one or more instance of an object that I only have a reference to it's interface?

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly, here is my simple pseudo code problem.

In this example, this is a data layer that has access to a reference to a project that contains the common interfaces, but not the concrete implementations. I would like to pass in (or inject) the List that will return a collection of one or more provider objects.

The problem is, I can't instantiate a new instance of a `IProvider` item for each record in the set returned by the stored procedure because I only have reference to the `IProvider` interface.

Would DI solve this? I still don't know how many instances of the `Provider` item to pass in, if any at the time I call into this method.

I have a feeling this is a pattern problem more than anything, but I can't wrap my head around the correct solution.

```
    public List<IProvider> GetProviders(List<IProvider> providers, IProvider provider)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Providers.usp_GetProviders";

        SQLDatabase db = new SQLDatabase();

        using(cmd.Connection = db.GetConnection())
        {

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                // Internal private method called for each row
                // needs a new instance of an IProvider
                MapDbToEntity(rdr, provider);
                providers.Add(provider);
            }
        }

        return providers;
    }
```

Comment: you will pass instance of class which inherites from IProvider and provides implementation

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes, but I don't know how many providers I need, and I will need to create a new instance for each row in the record-set. A pattern to accomplish this is escaping me.

Comment: For further clarity, the method call shows a parameter of IProvider provider - this is likely not correct, but not sure how to solver once inside this method, I can't new up a provider here as needed then populate and add to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to solve this is with a factory pattern.

The factory which implements an interface to create an object is injected into the lower data layer that doesn't know anything about the entities, only the interfaces.

*I'm NOT a pattern expert by any means so I'm looking for confirmation - this does work however.*

Keeping things simple:

```
namespace MyApplication.Common.Factory
{
    public interface IFactory
    {
        IProvider GetProvider();
    }
}
```

Then, in my business entity layer:

```
public class ProviderFactory : IFactory
{
    public IProvider GetProvider()
    {
        return new Provider();
    }

}
```

Which in turn allows me to call up and out to a factory to create an instance of an object which implements the IProvider interface:

```
    public List<IProvider> GetProviders(List<IProvider> providers, IFactory factory)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Providers.usp_GetProviders";

        SQLDatabase db = new SQLDatabase();

        using(cmd.Connection = db.GetConnection())
        {

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                IProvider provider = factory.GetProvider();

                MapDbToEntity(rdr, provider);
                providers.Add(provider);
            }
        }

        return providers;
    }
```